# Device build number hidden?

Tags: android, htc-android

I just got a new phone (HTC Desire) running android 4.4 and I am trying to set it up for development but I can't find the build number in order to tap it 7 times in order to reveal the development options, I've already been able to and had much luck with other phones but this one leaves me confused.

Answer (score 3):

What model of the HTC Desire do you have? For the 501, the build number should be located under: `Settings -> About -> Software information -> More`. Have you looked there?

Per Cricket's FAQ: http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-desire-510-cricket/faq/2/

Comment: your answer helped me solve same problem above... (y)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the different Android versions or the phone versions, but on different phones, it may be at different locations. Instead of "Build number" it might be "Software version" on some phones.

Most Android phones:

> “Settings”>”About”>Tap ”Build Number” 7 times quickly or more.

Other android phones:

> "Settings">"System Management">"About Phone">Tap "Software version" 7
> times quickly or more.

Just tap anything in "About" that has "build number" or "software info" or "software version" in it, as different phones seem to have different locations.